# Make React JS await for a async func to complete before running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, frontend

I'm trying to make react not load until after an axios get requests finishes. I'm pretty rough on react all around, so sorry in advance.

I'm getting an array of objects
`const { dogBreedsTest } = useApplicationData()`

And I need it to be the default value of one of my states
`const [dogBreeds, updateDogBreeds] = useState(dogBreedsTest);`

However, I'm getting an error that my value is coming up as null on the first iteration of my app starting. How can I ensure that my value has completed my request before my app tries to use it?

Here is how I am getting the data for useApplicationData()

```
const [dogBreedsTest, setDogBreeds] = useState(null);

  const getDogBreeds = async () => {
    try{
      const { data } = await axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
      if(data) {
        const newDogList = generateDogsArray(data['message'])
        const generatedDogs = selectedDogs(newDogList)
        setDogBreeds(generatedDogs)
        
      }
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getDogBreeds()
  }, []);

  return {
    dogBreedsTest,
    setDogBreeds
  }
```

And I am importing into my app and using:

```
import useApplicationData from "./hooks/useApplicationData";

const { dogBreedsTest } = useApplicationData()
  const [dogBreeds, updateDogBreeds] = useState(dogBreedsTest[0]);
  const [breedList1, updateBreedList1] = useState(dogBreedsTest[0])

function handleOnDragEnd(result) {
    if (!result.destination) return;

    const items = Array.from(dogBreeds);
    const [reorderedItem] = items.splice(result.source.index, 1);
    items.splice(result.destination.index, 0, reorderedItem);
    for (const [index, item] of items.entries()) {
      item['rank'] = index + 1
    }
    updateDogBreeds(dogBreedsTest[0]);
    updateBreedList1(dogBreedsTest[0])
  }
return (
<div className="flex-container">
      <div className="App-header">
          <h1>Dog Breeds 1</h1>
          <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleOnDragEnd}>
            <Droppable droppableId="characters">
              {(provided) => (
                <ul className="dogBreeds" {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
                  {breedList1?.map(({id, name, rank}, index) => {
                    return (
                      <Draggable key={id} draggableId={id} index={index}>
                        {(provided) => (
                          <li ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.draggableProps} {...provided.dragHandleProps}>
                            <p>
                              #{rank}:  { name }
                            </p>
                          </li>
                        )}
                      </Draggable>
                    );
                  })}
                  {provided.placeholder}
                </ul>
              )}
            </Droppable>
            </DragDropContext>
        </div>
)
```

error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null`
(I am mapping the data later in the program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const getDogBreeds = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
      if(data) {
        const newDogList = generateDogsArray(data['message'])
        const generatedDogs = selectedDogs(newDogList)
        setDogBreeds(generatedDogs)
      }
  } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
  }
}
  
useEffect(() => {
  getDogBreeds() // -> you are not awaiting this
}, []);
```

#### Do this instead

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
    .then(res => {
      const newDogList = generateDogsArray(res.data['message']);
      const generatedDogs = selectedDogs(newDogList);
      setDogBreeds(generatedDogs);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}, []);
```

I know this looks awful, but I don't think you should use `async/await` inside `useEffect`

#### Use this in your application

`useEffect` will update whenever `dogBreedsTest` is changed. In order to make it work, start with `null` values and update them to the correct initial values once your `async` operation is finished.

```
const { dogBreedsTest } = useApplicationData();
const [dogBreeds, updateDogBreeds] = useState(null);
const [breedList1, updateBreedList1] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  updateDogBreeds(dogBreedsTest[0]);
  updateBreedList1(dogBreedsTest[0]);
}, [dogBreedsTest]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry for the delay that solved what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that react first render and then run useEffect(), so if you don't want to render nothing before the axios, you need to tell to react, that the first render is null.

Where is your map function, to see the code? to show you it?.

I suppose that your data first is null. So you can use something like.

```
if(!data) return null
```

2nd Option:

```
    In your map try this:

   {breedList1 === null 
  ? null 
  : breedList1.map(({id, name, rank}, index) => (
     <Draggable 
      key={id} draggableId={id} index={index}>
                        {(provided) => (
                          <li ref={provided.innerRef}   {...provided.draggableProps} {...provided.dragHandleProps}>
                            <p>
                              #{rank}:  { name }
                            </p>
                          </li>
                        )}
                      </Draggable> ))}
```

You have null, because your axios is async and react try to render before any effect. So if you say to react that the list is null, react will render and load the data from the api in the second time.

Comment: Hey thanks for your tip, Unfortaunetly, anywhere I try to put that it doesnt work. I need this data to populate an important state when my page first loads. I don't necessarily have to render nothing before axios, its just I need this data for the app to work properly

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1 use the optional chaining operator

```
dogBreedsTest?.map()
```

### Option 2 check in the return if `dogBreedsTest` is an array

```
retrun (<>
    {Array.isArray(dogBreedsTest) && dogBreedsTest.map()}
</>)
```

### Option 3 return early

```
if (!Array.isArray(dogBreedsTest)) return null

retrun (<>
    {dogBreedsTest.map()}
</>)
```

### Option 4 set initial state

```
const [dogBreedsTest, setDogBreeds] = useState([]);
```

You could also add a loading state and add a loading spinner or something like that:

```
const [dogBreedsTest, setDogBreeds] = useState(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  const getDogBreeds = async () => {
    setLoading(true)

    try{
      const { data } = await axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
      if(data) {
        const newDogList = generateDogsArray(data['message'])
        const generatedDogs = selectedDogs(newDogList)
        setDogBreeds(generatedDogs)
        
      }
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    setLoading(false)
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getDogBreeds()
  }, []);

  return {
    dogBreedsTest,
    loading,
    setDogBreeds
  }
```

**Edit**

Try to use a `useEffect` hook to update the states when `dogBreedsTest` got set.

```
const { dogBreedsTest } = useApplicationData()
const [dogBreeds, updateDogBreeds] = useState(dogBreedsTest?.[0] ?? []);
const [breedList1, updateBreedList1] = useState(dogBreedsTest?.[0] ?? [])

useEffect(() => {
    updateDogBreeds(dogBreedsTest?.[0] ?? [])
    updateBreedList1(dogBreedsTest?.[0] ?? [])
}, [dogBreedsTest])
```

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, I can't quite get any of them to work, I do really like the idea of the loading value but I'm just not that competent to make that work well

Comment: I used it mostly like if (loading) return <Spinner />

Comment: And then in the normal retrun {!loading && dataArray?.length > 0 && dataArray?.map()}

Comment: I updated my example not sure if that will help make it more clear

Comment: Added also an edit maybe it helps.